# How can I copy an input value to a div?

Tags: javascript, input

I'm starting to learn JavaScript now and I'm still very confused.
I'm on a project where I need something to work from the following example: I have two buttons: "**blue**" and "**green**", when the user clicks on "**blue**" this is printed on a div showing the phrase "**the color blue**" or "**the color green**" if clicked on "**green**".

Here is an example of my HTML:

```html
    <p>Select:</p>
    <input value="blue" type="button" />
    <input value="green" type="button" />
    
    <div id="here-appears-thecolourchosen"></div>
```

Can you help me please? Thank you sooooo much!

edit: not need to copy the name of the colors, just to customize a phrase when it is chosen.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<p>Select:</p>
<input value="blue" type="button" />
<input value="green" type="button" />

<div id="here-appears-thecolourchosen"></div>
```

//javascript

```
<script>
var btn=document.querySelectorAll("input[type=button]");
for(var i=0;i<btn.length;i++){
btn[i].addEventListener("click",function(e){
document.getElementById("here-appears-thecolourchosen").innerText="the color 
"+this.value;
});
}
```

//jquery

```
<script>
$("input[type=button]").click(function(){
$("#here-appears-thecolourchosen").text($(this).val());
});
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome.if you find it helpful please make it as answer

Answer (score 0):

- Use the function `addEventListener` to bind events to your elements.
- Use the following functions `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` to get your elements.

```js
document.querySelector('[name="estados-mexico"]').addEventListener('change', function() {
  document.getElementById('here-appears-thestatechosen').innerHTML = `${this.value} - ${this.options[this.selectedIndex].innerText}`
});

document.querySelectorAll('[type="button"]').forEach(function(e) {
  e.addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('here-appears-thecolourchosen').innerHTML = this.value;
  });
})
```

```html
<p>Select:</p>
<input value="blue" type="button" />
<input value="green" type="button" />
<br>
<select name="estados-mexico">
    <option value="AC">Acre</option>
    <option value="AL">Alagoas</option>
    <option value="AP">Amapá</option>
</select>

<div id="here-appears-thecolourchosen"></div>
<div id="here-appears-thestatechosen"></div>
```

## Resources

- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Answer (score 0):

As I've understand, you need pure js. Try this code, its print value from clicked button:

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i += 1) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    document.getElementById('here-appears-thecolourchosen').innerText = 'The color is ' + this.value;
 });
}
```

```html
    <p>Select:</p>
    <input value="blue" type="button" />
    <input value="green" type="button" />
    
    <div id="here-appears-thecolourchosen"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var btns = document.querySelectorAll('INPUT');
var div = document.getElementById('here-appears-thecolourchosen');

for(var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    if(this.value === 'blue') {
      div.textContent = 'The Color Blue';
    }
    else if (this.value === 'green') {
       div.textContent = 'The Color Green';
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```html
<p>Select:</p>
    <input value="blue" type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('colorChosen').innerText='blue'" />
    <input value="green" type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('colorChosen').innerText='green'" />
    <br>
    <select name="estados-mexico">
    <option value="AC">Acre</option>
    <option value="AL">Alagoas</option>
    <option value="AP">Amapá</option>
    </select>
    <div id="colorChosen"></div>
    <div id="stateChosen"></div>
```

I did inline JS to set the text inside the first div.  Using this example, try to figure out how to handle the second issue with the states.

Comment: If someone is learning JavaScript, the first thing one **should not do** is show them a solution that is _far_ removed from any sane modern practice. The inline JS has got to go.

Comment: I know.. but generally I learn more by looking at examples and trying to understand their logic

Comment: @RandyCasburn I understand your point, my intention was not to unnecessarily confuse OP by a script block, waiting for the DOM to finish, subscribing to the event, etc.